# Silex: How to create a loop in Form

Tags: php, forms, loops, foreach, silex

The following lines of code get me a Silex Form. One text-field and one checkbox. The text-field contains the name of a team. The checkboxes should contain the username of a user, so that I can add them to the team.

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 4,'max' => 64))),
            'label' => 'Team Name',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'value' => $team->data()->name),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
        ))
        ->add('players', CheckboxType::class, [
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
                'label' => $player->username,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'value' => $player->username),
                'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Edit',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
        ])
        ->getForm();
```

I can get my list of users using the following lines:

```
$user = new User()
$user->getList();

foreach($user->data() as $player){
        ->add('players', CheckboxType::class, [
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
                'label' => $player->username,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'value' => $player->username),
                'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
        ])
    }
```

However, I don't know how to combine these two parts, since the $form variable is defined in one 'line' with a ';' at the end. How can I break this $form into parts so that I can loop through my users and add a checkbox for every user?

Comment: Just add all your `add()` (including loop) methods before doing `$form->getForm();`

Comment: So could you give me the script how you would do it? Because I still have doubts on how to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is "generated" once you execute `->getForm();` so if you want to add anyfield before generating it, you should finish by `->getForm();`

So your code should probably look like:

```
// add you "static" fields
$formBuilder = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
    ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
        'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 4,'max' => 64))),
        'label' => 'Team Name',
        'required' => 'required',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'value' => $team->data()->name),
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
    ))
    ->add('players', CheckboxType::class, [
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
            'label' => $player->username,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'value' => $player->username),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
    ])
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Edit',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
    ]);


 $user = new User();
 $user->getList();

// then add your "dynamic" fields 

foreach($user->data() as $player) {
    $formBuilder->add('players', CheckboxType::class, [
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
            'label' => $player->username,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'value' => $player->username),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label')
    ]);
}


// then generate your form
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```